# Get the index of the push button

Tags: python, pyside2

I have the following problem, which doesn't seem particularly difficult, but I've been standing still for 1 day and can't find the right logic.

I have a list that searches for objects that end with the name "_ctrl". This list currently contains 4 items, but can contain any number of items. Depending on how many objects exist, it will add that many rows of buttons to the table.

My question is - how to get the index of the selected button to be printed in another function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zmIP.png)

I hope you can understand me what I wanted to ask.

```
def refresh_table(self):
    self.table_wdg.setRowCount(0)
    controls = cmds.ls("*_ctrl")
        
    for i in range(len(controls)):
        self.table_wdg.insertRow(i)
            
        controls[i] = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self.table_wdg.setCellWidget(i,0,controls[i])
            
        controls[i].clicked.connect(self.printing)
        
        
def printing(self):
    print()
```

Comment: try passing the index of the button to `printing` as an argument.

Comment: in this case prints the indexes one after another. I would like to have: If I click the first button, then it prints 0

Comment: `connect(lambda *args, i=i: self.printing(i))`.